# Equilibrium Solutions and Stabiity (ODE's)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found the following question on one of my tutorial sheets for mathematics:

Find the equilibrium solutions to the following Ordinary Differential Equation,

$$y' = x^2 ~ \cos^3(y)$$

Which of theses solutions are stable?

I understand that the equilibrium solutions are $~x=0~$ and $~y=90,270,\cdots ~$.

However, I was unsure how to identify if they were stable or not.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: by the way, whenever you're dealing with trigonometric functions in calculus, you should always use the radian measure, not degrees. So, $y = \pi/2, 3\pi/2, \dots$

Comment: also, your wording with the equilibrium is a little weird, so I'm not sure if you realize this or not, but in fact there are whole lines of equilibrium: the line $x=0$, i.e $\{0\} \times \Bbb{R}$  and the set of horizontal lines $ \bigcup\limits_{k \in \Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{R} \times \left\{ \frac{(2k+1) \pi}{2} \right\}$ are all equilibria. (if you already knew this then just ignore the comment)